# GL.BlendFuncSeparate(ArbDrawBuffersBlend) Enum has no members?

Tags: opentk

I want to use the function GL.BlendFuncSeparate but it seems that one of the enums used has no members.

```
    public enum ArbDrawBuffersBlend
    {

    }
```

Is there another function to call or is this a bug?